# Any way to send media group with keyboard?

Tags: python, keyboard, media, group, pyrogram

I'm trying to send a media group with a keyboard, but I don't understand how to do it.
Here is the doc: https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/send_media_group#pyrogram.Client.send_media_group
There is no function or arg to implement a keyboard. is there any way to do this?

It should add keybord to the media group